# exec not working when creating functions from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, setter, getter

Long story short, i'm testing some dynamic property injection on methods in python.

right now I have the problem that when I call exec() on my getter and setter strings to turn them into dynamiclly created function, they stay strings.

```
def _injectProperties(self): 
        """docstring"""

        for p in self.InputParameters:
            index = p.Order
            name = p.Name.lstrip('@')
            pName = p.Name

            fnGet = (
                "def get(self): \n"
                "    rtnVal = [p.Value for p in self.InputParameters "
                "        if p.Name == '{0}'][0] \n"
                "    return rtnVal ").format(p.Name)

            fnSet = (
                "def set(self, value): \n"
                "    prop = [p for p in self.InputParameters "
                "        if p.Name == '{0}'][0] \n"
                "    prop.Value = value \n"
                "    return ").format(p.Name)

            exec(fnGet) in locals()
            exec(fnSet) in locals()

            self._addprop(name, fnGet, fnSet)

        return
```

So basically in the code above `_addprop` is a function that simply creates a copy of the class and and sets a property to it as such:

```
setattr(cls, name, property(fget=getter, fset=setter, fdel=destructor, doc=docstring))
```

why in this context do the `fnGet` and `fnSet` variables still reference the string representation of the get and set function after I call `exec(fnGet)` and `exec(fnSet)`?

Comment: Change the exec to setattr(object, funname, anonymous_function)

Comment: Why would you expect the `exec` to turn your `fnGet` and `fnSet` variables into (I assume) functions?

Comment: By the way, the `exec <code> in <scope>` syntax has been removed in python 3. You should be using `exec(<code>, <scope>)`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey it does in other algorithms i'm using.  As i understand it, the way Python works, it executes code once to build function objects when it imports a module for the first time, so it's the same process as doing that.  If you exec a string that is written like a function the variable will afterward refer to a function that was defined by that string.  You can easily test this in an interactive window.  The code above in fact works if pasted into my interactive window, just not when testing on an object. I'd be willing to bet there's some context distinction i'm flubbing here.

Comment: That only happens if your string variable has the same name as the function, though. In that case the function definition overwrites the variable. But your functions are named `get`/`set`, not `fnGet`/`fnSet`.

Comment: @JamieMarshall there's no need to go to this much trouble anyway. Instead of exec'ing to add methods, you can define `__getattr__` to deal with undefined attributes.

Comment: @NedBatchelder admittedly this is my first foray trying this type of injection.  Could you post an example of what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. so I made up something runnable to illustrate how you could do this (although I think @Ned Batchelder probably has a better suggestion).

Note this also shows what I think is a better to way to embed the functions' source code.

```
from textwrap import dedent

class InputParameter:  # Mock for testing
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.InputParameters = [  # For testing
            InputParameter(Order=42, Name='@foobar'),
        ]

    def _addprop(self, name, getter, setter):
        print('_addprop({!r}, {}, {})'.format(name, getter, setter))

    def _injectProperties(self):
            """docstring"""

            for p in self.InputParameters:
                index = p.Order
                name = p.Name.lstrip('@')
                pName = p.Name

                fnGet = dedent("""
                    def get(self):
                        rtnVal = [p.Value for p in self.InputParameters
                                    if p.Name == '{0}'][0]
                        return rtnVal
                """).format(p.Name)

                fnSet = dedent("""
                    def set(self, value):
                        prop = [p for p in self.InputParameters
                                    if p.Name == '{0}'][0]
                        prop.Value = value
                        return
                """).format(p.Name)

                locals_dict = {}
                exec(fnGet, globals(), locals_dict)
                exec(fnSet, globals(), locals_dict)

                self._addprop(name, locals_dict['get'], locals_dict['set'])

            return

cls = Class()
cls._injectProperties()
```

Output:

```
_addprop('foobar', <function get at 0x00270858>, <function set at 0x00572C00>)
```

Comment: Yep, that's it, stoopid syntax error on my part.  `locals_dict['get']` was the part that was getting me.  When testing in my interactive environment the name of my getter was the same as the variable holding the string representation.  In my test/question that's not the case.  Very good catch.

Comment: @Jamie: Glad to hear it solved your problem. Also note that when using `exec()`, you should generally pass it an empty "locals" dictionary if the code being executed creates any variables that you want to retrieve afterwards. This is because the default value it uses it the `locals()` dictionary, which should not (can't reliably) be modified.

Comment: @JamieMarshall even the author of this answer thinks that "@Ned Batchelder probably has a better suggestion". :)  This is a lot of code that you don't need...

Comment: @NedBatchelder,  you're solution is very relevant, but there were a few reason I view this as superior for my build.  I've commented on your answer to explain further.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using exec to inject properties, you can use `__getattr__`. It's called when an attribute is missing.

I think this does what you need:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    for p in self.InputParameters:
        if p.Name == attr:
            return p.Value

def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    for p in self.InputParameters:
        if p.Name == attr:
            p.Value = value
            break
```

Comment: My concern with this solution is that intellisense won't pick up the properties and thus other programmers on my team will have to know the content of the objects in the self.InputParameters list prior to it being usable.  Also, this is attached to objects so its not particularly modular if I want to use injection across multiple classes.  These are the reasons I marked @martineau's answer as "the answer".   I can easily put that code into a helper class and call it on any other class I wan't to inject attributes.